# Dataflow CoGroupByKey is very slow for more than 10000 elements per key

Tags: java, left-join, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two `PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>>` one has ~7 Million rows and the other has ~1 Million rows.

What I want to do is apply left outer join between these two PCollections and in case of successful join put all the data of right TableRow To left TableRow and return the results.

I have tried using CoGroupByKey in apache beam SDK 2.10.0 for java and here I am getting so many Hot Keys so my Fetching Result after CoGrupByKey is getting slower with Waring 'More 10000 elements per key, need to reiterate'. I have also tried shuffle mode service but no help.

```java
PCollection<TableRow> finalResultCollection =
coGbkResultCollection.apply(ParDo.of(
  new DoFn<KV<K, CoGbkResult>, TableROw>() {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      KV<K, CoGbkResult> e = c.element();
      // Get all collection 1 values
      Iterable<TableRow> pt1Vals = e.getValue().getAll(t1);
      Iterable<TableRow> pt2Vals = e.getValue().getAll(t2);
      for (TableRow tr : pt1Vals)
      {
        TableRow out = tr.clone();
        if(pt2Vals.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            for (TableRow tr1 : pt2Vals)
            {
                out.putAll(tr1);
                c.output(out);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            c.output(out);
        }

      }
    }
  }));
```

What is the way to perform these type of joins in dataflow?

Comment: Is one of your PCollection bounded? If one side is bounded, it might be worth to try a side input join where you convert one PCollection to a side input. It's like doing a classic hash join. Ideally you can make the larger PCollection as sideinput so only iterate a smaller set.

Comment: Also, checked TableRow's code and seems like it is expensive class (save values into a map, etc.)  So does clone and other operations seem like expensive and slow. You might also want to try something else than TableRow.

Comment: i have tried sideinput also but it is slower too.

Comment: Try use highmem  for machine types. this is machine type for high memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some research and I have found some information that can help you.

The data sent transferred by dataflow between PCollections (serializable objects) may not exist in a single machine. Furthermore, a transformation like GroupByKey/CoGroupByKey needs requires all the data to collected in one place before the resultant populated, I don't know if you  have it in a different structure.

Besides you can redistribute your keys, put less workers and add more memory, or, try using [Combine.perKey](https://blog.softwaremill.com/let-mortal-combat-begin-apache-beams-groupbykey-vs-combine-perkey-29e4feb7291).

Also you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229309/dataflow-groupbykey-and-cogroupbykey-is-very-slow) workaround, or, you can read [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/writing-dataflow-pipelines-with-scalability-in-mind) article and have more information that can help you.